# Use AppCompat themes with framework activity

Tags: android

I want to use `Theme.Appcompat.Light` as the application theme to introduce Material Design to platform version 19:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

But I don't quite like extending support library `ActionBarActivity` since I'm not going to support platforms below version 19 and the framework `Activity` should already have an action bar in platform version 19.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the recent post on [getting started with AppCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html):

> If you are not currently using AppCompat, or you are starting from scratch, here's how to set it up:
>
> All of your Activities must extend from ActionBarActivity, which extends from FragmentActivity from the v4 support library, so you can continue to use fragments.

So to answer your question

> Is this possible?

No it is not. You need to extend from `ActionBarActivity` to use the `Theme.Appcompat.Light`, even if you're not planning to support anything under v19.

Comment: Thanks for an almost perfect answer. But why would choosing a theme affect which class to use in the source code? Well, man...